# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)

Tags: php, sms-gateway

Its my first time when i am trying to integrate a sms gateway and I am poorly trapped in it and don't understand how to overcome with this problem. Please help me out,

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

$user = "parshwawebsolutions";
$password = "12646";
$senderid = "PARSHWA";
$smsurl = "http://sms.parshwawebsolutions.com/ComposeSMS.aspx?";

function httpRequest($url){
    $pattern = "/http...([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*).([0-9]*).(.*)/";
    preg_match($pattern,$url,$args);
    $in = "";
    $fp = fsockopen($args[1],80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
       return("$errstr ($errno)");
    } else {
  $args[3] = "C".$args[3];
        $out = "GET /$args[3] HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: $args[1]:$args[2]\r\n";
        $out .= "User-agent: PARSHWA WEB SOLUTIONS\r\n";
        $out .= "Accept: */*\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fwrite($fp, $out);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
           $in.=fgets($fp, 128);
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return($in);
}



function SMSSend($phone, $msg, $debug=false){
      global $user,$password,$senderid,$smsurl;

      $url = 'username='.$user;
      $url.= '&password='.$password;
      $url.= '&sender='.$senderid;
      $url.= '&to='.urlencode($phone);
      $url.= '&message='.urlencode($msg);
      $url.= '&priority=1';
      $url.= '&dnd=1';
      $url.= '&unicode=0';


      $urltouse =  $smsurl.$url;
      if ($debug) { echo "Request: <br>$urltouse<br><br>"; }

      //Open the URL to send the message
      $response = httpRequest($urltouse);
      if ($debug) {
           echo "Response: <br><pre>".
           str_replace(array("<",">"),array("&lt;","&gt;"),$response).
           "</pre><br>"; }

      return($response);
}

$phonenum = $_POST['recipient'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$debug = true;

SMSSend($phonenum,$message,$debug);

?>
```

and i am getting the error like this:

Response:

php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you rolling your own HTTP client stack (which by the way is flawed in various ways). PHP comes with a built in HTTP client and the curl extension.